# Screen tearing issue with HP 15 (AMDGPU)

Tags: screen, hp, 18.04, amdgpu

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 to try out new features of it. Immediately I installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and updated the system after installation because I didn't connect my laptop to the Internet for some reason.

However, I forgot to backup my `.conf` file of AMDGPU, which I used earlier with 16.04 install to eliminate the screen tearing issue.

Using modified configuration [from this blog](https://cubethethird.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/eliminate-screen-tearing-with-amd-gpu-on-ubuntu/) doesn't help me, as it throws me to `tty` screen or simply hung up the laptop and not accepting any input, which forces me to do REISUB.

Here is the configuration I tried:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier "AMD"
   Driver  "amdgpu"
   Option  "DRI" "3"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Laptop used is HP Notebook - 15-ba077cl. Dump of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA`:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo [1002:9874] (rev c9)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Carrizo [103c:81f9]
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Dump of `inxi -F` is at this link: https://pastebin.com/raw/94izdgFg

**Update:** I tried using packages from `ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/mesa` but the screen tearing still there.

How do I eliminate the screen tearing issue, then?

Comment: 18.04 is not officially supported by AMD.  Which driver did you install and how?

Comment: @Fabby I remembered it was an open-source AMD driver, which I simply install via update. I'll update the question.

Comment: Yup, those seem to be the latest drivers published from AMD for your chipset.  File a bug with AMD...

Comment: I think I know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some of dirty attempt, and finally resolved my own problem. However, this answer only applies to `xorg`, not `wayland` as screen tearing doesn't appear when I'm using it.

First, make sure that your packages are up-to-date, as it's essential.

Since I'm using Unity, playing around with `ccsm` by toggling on *Force complete redraw on inital damage* and *Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint* seemed like resolving it. I don't know if GNOME also uses `compiz`.

I realized that there was something wrong with my config file;

```
Option "TearFree" "true"
```

That is the correct string, since the option only accepts boolean input(?). Previously, I tried playing with DRI and TearFree setting; using only one of them renders to unaccessible desktop. I don't have an idea why.

Reboot and the screen tearing is gone!

Comment: Cool! Too bad you can't award your bounty to yourself!  Now it's lost forever! (+1 to Q, +1 to A = 15 back already!)

Comment: I wonder if there is a faster way to resolve this, since this problem gave me a headache for almost a week-

Answer (score 1):

No one from the AMD world has answered yet. I'm in the Intel/nVidia camp but I'll suggest you try this instead of your current setup:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMD"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: Radeon doesn't work at all on my VGA, sorry.

Comment: @AryoAdhi I changed Radeon to AMD. My May 17th answer was similar to your accepted answer of May 18th.

Comment: Only applying that string crashes X server on me. Don't know why.

Comment: Can you update your question with the X server log?

Comment: Actually, this allows me to enter X server successfully. However, most of the additional features are unused.